# How to load a file as a context parameter value in a Tomcat/Java/Spring application?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat7

I'm using my context.xml file to set init parameters for my java application, for example:

```
<Parameter
    name="Environment"
    description="The environment in which this code is running (e.g. Production, Staging, Development)."
    value="Production"/>
```

I would like to be able to create a parameter who's value attribute is loading from a file.  Is there anyway to do this?  Should I be using a `< Resource >` element instead?  If so, how do I setup a resource to load the contents of a file?  I've tried Google, but I my not understand the context.xml file well enough to know what to look for.  Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In application-context.xml add this element

```
<context:property-placeholder ignore-unresolvable="true" location="classpath*:application.properties"/>
```

In the file application.properties you can define parameters like this

```
userName=root
password=123
```

And then you can use the parameters by this way

```
    <property name="username"  value="${userName}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${password}"/>
```

Comment: I was actually hoping to use the entire contents of the file as a single value.